# apply focus to a element

Tags: html, css

I have these three size buttons. The hover feature works where if you hover, it changes the background color. However, I want it to stay that color when you select it.

So, I tried adding the `focus` to the css file and it doesn't seem to work. I want this to be done using pure css. No javascript answers please :)

```css
.sizes {
  font-family: Andale Mono;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Ssize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Msize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Lsize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Ssize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Ssize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes">
  <a id="sa" class="Ssize">S</a>
  <a id="ma" class="Msize">M</a>
  <a id="la" class="Lsize">L</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by exploiting the tabindex attribute :)

```css
.sizes {
  font-family: Andale Mono;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Ssize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Msize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Lsize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Ssize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Ssize:active {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Ssize[tabindex]:focus {
    background-color: #ffb5d5;
    outline: none;
}

.Msize:active {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize[tabindex]:focus {
    background-color: #ffb5d5;
    outline: none;
}

.Lsize:active {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize[tabindex]:focus {
    background-color: #ffb5d5;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes">
  <a id="sa" tabindex="1" class="Ssize">S</a>
  <a id="ma" tabindex="1" class="Msize">M</a>
  <a id="la" tabindex="1" class="Lsize">L</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` instead of `a`.

```css
.sizes {
  font-family: Andale Mono;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Ssize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Msize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Lsize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Ssize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Ssize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:focus {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes">
  <button id="sa" class="Ssize">S</button>
  <button id="ma" class="Msize">M</button>
  <button id="la" class="Lsize">L</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When you click the button, the background still doesn't change. Only when you hover it changes. @dinindu

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Javascript.
Using Javascript, you can define the event handler when the button is clicked and can change the style by toggling the class with `background-change` as follows.

```js
let prevItem = null;

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    item.classList.toggle('active');
    if (prevItem == item) {
      return;
    }
    if (prevItem) {
      prevItem.classList.remove('active');
    }
    prevItem = item;
  });
});
```

```css
.sizes {
  font-family: Andale Mono;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Ssize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Msize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Lsize {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Ssize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Msize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.Lsize:hover {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ffb5d5;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes">
  <a id="sa" class="Ssize">S</a>
  <a id="ma" class="Msize">M</a>
  <a id="la" class="Lsize">L</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Can you add one small fix. Two buttons can't be highlighted at the same time. If you click "S" it should be the only one that can be highlighted. So if "S" is already highlighted and you click "M", it switches the background color so only "M" is highlighted. Does this make sense?